What is the right way to apply a function to a value in a ConcurrentHashMap in C++?
I am using folly::ConccurentHashMap and I want to have a frequency counter of std::string
Is there an API to "insert 1 if key is missing otherwise update value of 1" atomically?
I thought of
 auto [it, _] = numOccurences.emplace(str, 1);
 it->second = it->second + 1;

but I am not sure if it's atomic, and it complains about const reference of the second value.

it->second = it->second + 1; is certainly not atomic.

"it complaints about const reference of the second value" -- Without seeing the complaint, I can only guess, but my guess is that the value in question is const because what you are trying to do is not atomic. That is, someone intentionally made something const so that the compiler would detect an unsafe update.

Because operator[] returns a copy and iterators are not a thread-safe option, folly::ConcurrentHashMap provides the insert_or_assign operation as a thread-safe means by which you can perform a "insert if key isn't present otherwise update value" operation.
  /*
   * The bool component will always be true if the map has been updated via
   * either insertion or assignment. Note that this is different from the
   * std::map::insert_or_assign interface.
   */
  template <typename Key, typename Value>
  std::pair<ConstIterator, bool> insert_or_assign(Key&& k, Value&& v);

In order to atomically increment a value, as correctly pointed out by @Mooning Duck in the comments, you will need to use a method like assign_if_equal to perform an atomic CAS. There is no insert_or_assign_if_equal, however, you can achieve this with an insert and a assign_if_equal in a loop.

Note that insert_or_assign is insufficient for atomic increment.

I think you need assign_if_equal in a loop

I'm sort of surprised. Ideally this would have some sort of mutate_value_in_spinlock method that could do an atomic_increment, but it doesn't seem to have anything of the sort.

Thank you, that's a good point. There is assign_if_equal but unfortunately no insert_or_assign_if_equal. Some combination of methods will be needed.
